# How to combine different rows and get mean value for columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average

I have the following df which contains 2 types of information. The first one is the characteristics of the item (some are strings and others are integers). The other type is regarding emission values of the said item (in a float format).

| Charact. 1 | Charact. 2 | Charact. 3 | Emission 1 | Emission 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1998 | AB | C | 1 | 2 |
| 1998 | AB | C | 3 | 4 |
| 2000 | AB | C | 1 | 2 |
| 2001 | DE | F | 1 | 2 |
| 2001 | DE | F | 3 | 4 |

I would like to combine the items which have the same 3 characteristics and get the mean value of the 2 emissions to get the following df :

| Charact. 1 | Charact. 2 | Charact. 3 | Emission 1 | Emission 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1998 | AB | C | 2 | 3 |
| 2000 | AB | C | 1 | 2 |
| 2001 | DE | F | 2 | 3 |

I have tried this line of code to get it to work but it gives me an error

`df.groupby(['Charact. 1', 'Charact. 2', 'Charact. 3'], as_index=False).agg({'Emission 1': 'mean', 'Emission 2': 'mean',})`

The specific error says : ValueError: Length of values (10345) does not match length of index (10687600)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue with the data and code you've provided. Are you attempting to assign this groupby aggregation somewhere? A groupby agg alone cannot produce this error as far as I know.

Comment: @ddejohn, did you downvote? any reason?

Comment: I am downvoting everybody that misreads the question entirely and posts code that does not help OP. OP's method of finding the mean is 1) a valid solution, and 2) *not the problem OP is asking about*.

Comment: OP, your error is likely caused by you attempting to assign those results back to your original dataframe. Please post clarifying information on what you are trying to do. Using `.agg()` with a dictionary of column names and aggregation functions **is not what is causing the problem** -- it is a perfectly valid way to achieve your desired result.

Comment: @ddejohn I don't believe the answers are misreading the question, which is essentially "How would I combine rows with the same characteristics, aggregating their data via averages?" Trying to reproduce this does show that OP's solution should work, but that doesn't mean the other answers provided are invalid in my opinion.

Comment: @ddejohn On my end `df = df.groupby(['c1', 'c2', 'c3'], as_index=False).agg({'e1': 'mean', 'e2': 'mean'})` does in fact work without error-- it still may be a problem with assigning values back to the original dataframe if OP has left out context but that alone shouldn't cause this problem either

Comment: @ddejohn you were right! 
I was trying to assign the results back to the original df instead of a new one.
Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
df.groupby(['Charact. 1','Charact. 2', 'Charact. 3'])[['Emission 1','Emission 2']].mean()
```

```
                                       Emission 1   Emission 2
Charact. 1  Charact. 2  Charact. 3      
1998             AB              C           2.0    3.0
2000             AB              C           1.0    2.0
2001             DE              F           2.0    3.0
```

Comment: @Mikel Alba, does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for the help, It was actually an error of trying to assign the results back to the original dataframe.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1998, 1998, 2000, 2001, 2001],
                   'c2': ['AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'DE', 'DE'],
                   'c3': ['C', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'F'],
                   'e1': [1, 3, 1, 1, 3],
                   'e2': [2, 4, 2, 2, 4]})
print(df.groupby(['c1','c2','c3'], as_index=False).mean())    

# Output:
#      c1  c2 c3  e1  e2                                
# 0  1998  AB  C   2   3
# 1  2000  AB  C   1   2
# 2  2001  DE  F   2   3
```

Edit: This also worked for me, so I'm not sure where exactly the problem lies in your code-- perhaps the DataFrame is structured somewhat differently compared to what your question implies?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1998, 1998, 2000, 2001, 2001],
                   'c2': ['AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'DE', 'DE'],
                   'c3': ['C', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'F'],
                   'e1': [1, 3, 1, 1, 3],
                   'e2': [2, 4, 2, 2, 4]})
print(df.groupby(['c1','c2','c3'], as_index=False).agg({'e1': 'mean', 'e2': 'mean',}))

# Output:
#      c1  c2 c3  e1  e2
# 0  1998  AB  C   2   3
# 1  2000  AB  C   1   2
# 2  2001  DE  F   2   3
```

Comment: Reassigning the value of `df` would not reproduce OP's error. It would only occur if OP was trying to set a specific column (or set of columns). The error is saying that the resultant aggregation has fewer values than the target dataframe has rows. Pandas therefore would not be able to figure out how OP wanted those values distributed, so it raises the error instead of guessing.

Answer (score -1):

```py
columns = ["1","2","3","E1","E2"]
row1 = ["1998",
"1998",
"2000",
"2001",
"2001"]
row2 = ["AB",
"AB",
"AB",
"DE",
"DE"]
row3 = ["C",
"C",
"C",
"F",
"F"]
row4 = [1,
3,
1,
1,
3]
row5 = [2,
4,
2,
2,
4]
                
df = pd.DataFrame([row1, row2, row3, row4, row5]).T
df.columns = columns

df.groupby(["1","2","3"]).agg('mean').reset_index()
```

results in the way that you want

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).